# C# Regex to disallow whitespaces

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a validation with Regex, and I had a no whitespaces variable, but it's throwing an error (despite getting the regex from another similar code example).

```
var noSpaces = new Regex(@"?!.* ");
var hasNum = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
var isValid = noSpaces.IsMatch(input) && hasNum.IsMatch(input);
```

The code is within a method that verifies password specifications, and this one pulls the error `system.text.regularexpressions.regexparseexception invalid pattern`. So, there has to be something wrong with the no whitespace regex input. The `isValid` bool is then used in an if statement, to either make the user re-input the password or move to the next method.

(I'm relatively new to C# and regex, so it could just be a simple typo, but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks!)

Comment: Your first pattern starts with a question mark. Do you want that as part of the pattern (a literal question mark) or as a modifier for something? In addition, there's a much simpler pattern for "whitespace".

Comment: I'm really not sure... I had just copied the contents within the brackets after someone had said that it was the regex for no whitespaces. I just want the regex to confirm that there are no whitespaces within the inputted password

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is simply testing if a string has any whitespace characters or not, the only pattern you need is `\s`. One or more match will indicate that there are whitespaces in the input.

```
Regex whitespacePattern = new Regex(@"\s");
bool inputHasWhitespace = whitespacePattern.IsMatch(input);
```

---

To explain why `?!.*`  is an invalid pattern:

The `?` symbol is a quantifier for the previous symbol meaning "zero or one". For example `a\d?` would match on an "a" followed by zero or one digits.

But, there isn't a symbol proceeding `?`, thus it's invalid.

Now, you *could* have been trying to do a *negative lookahead*. That would be `(?!.*)`, *with* the parentheses. If you're incorporating multiple password validation rules into one regex pattern, you *may* need to resort to that. But for making a single regex pattern to check if there are any whitespace characters, it's not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was probably something so simple!